# Round labels and sum values in label-value pair 2d-numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2d-Numpy array containing basically a label-value pair. I have combined several of these matricies, but I'm hoping to round the label to 4 decimal places and sum the values, such that:

```
[[70.00103, 1],
[70.02474, 1],
[70.02474, 1],
[70.024751, 1],
[71.009100, 1],
[79.0152, 1],
[79.0152633, 1],
[79.0152634, 1]]
```

becomes

```
[[70.001, 1],
[70.0247, 2],
[70.0248, 1],
[71.0091, 1],
[79.0152, 1],
[79.0153, 2]]
```

Any thoughts on how one might accomplish this in a speedy manner, using either numpy or pandas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [10]:

```
import numpy as np
x=np.array([[70.00103, 1],[70.02474, 1],[70.02474, 1],[70.024751, 1],[71.009100, 1],[79.0152, 1],[79.0152633, 1],[79.0152634,1]])
x[:,0]=x[:,0].round(4)
x
```

Out[10]:

```
 array([[ 70.001 ,   1.    ],
           [ 70.0247,   1.    ],
           [ 70.0247,   1.    ],
           [ 70.0248,   1.    ],
           [ 71.0091,   1.    ],
           [ 79.0152,   1.    ],
           [ 79.0153,   1.    ],
           [ 79.0153,   1.    ]])
```

In [14]:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(x).groupby(0).sum()
```

Out[14]:

```
70.0010 1
70.0247 2
70.0248 1
71.0091 1
79.0152 1
79.0153 2
```

Answer (score 0):

It's what that [`np.around`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.around.html) is for :

```
>>> A=np.array([[70.00103, 1],
... [70.02474, 1],
... [70.02474, 1],
... [70.024751, 1],
... [71.009100, 1],
... [79.0152, 1],
... [79.0152633, 1],
... [79.0152634, 1]])
>>> 
>>> np.around(A, decimals=4)
array([[ 70.001 ,   1.    ],
       [ 70.0247,   1.    ],
       [ 70.0247,   1.    ],
       [ 70.0248,   1.    ],
       [ 71.0091,   1.    ],
       [ 79.0152,   1.    ],
       [ 79.0153,   1.    ],
       [ 79.0153,   1.    ]])
```

Comment: Thanks! What about the combining and summing portion?